# SelectedDate not working for Calendar object

Tags: asp.net

Am trying to set a new date for Calendar object on ASP.NET , but nothing changed. Here is my code :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        cld_birth.SelectedDate = new DateTime(2003, 1, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try setting the `VisibleDate` as well:

```
if (Page.IsPostBack)
{
    cld_birth.SelectedDate = new DateTime(2003, 1, 1);
    cld_birth.VisibleDate = new DateTime(2003, 1, 1);
}
```

Comment: Because the ``VisibleDate`` property determines which month/date to show on the calendar, while ``SelectedDate`` just selects it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.visibledate.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.selecteddate.aspx

Answer (score 3):

There is an additional issue where the selected date is not highlighted (ie SelectedDayStyle is ignored) if the date contains a non-midnight time. 
You'd expect the first option to be ok. 
No, unfortunately

```
            Dim oDt As New Date()
            oDt = Now                
            Dim oDtYesterday As New Date
            oDtYesterday = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -1, oDt)

            'oDtYesterday is all fine, but does not highlight
            'calDateFrom.SelectedDate = oDtYesterday 

            Dim sDateYesterday As String
            sDateYesterday = Format(oDtYesterday, "dd MMM yyyy")

            Dim oDtY As New Date
            oDtY = CDate(sDateYesterday & " 12:00:00 AM")

            calDateFrom.SelectedDate = oDtY 
            calDateFrom.VisibleDate = calDateFrom.SelectedDate
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the time when the page is loaded for the first time then use **[IsPostBack Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.ispostback.aspx)** to determine if the page is loaded for the first time or if the page is Posted back.

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        cld_birth.SelectedDate = new DateTime(2003, 1, 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You must define `SelectedDayStyle` in your control.

```
<asp:Calendar ID="cld_birth" runat="server">
   <SelectedDayStyle Font-Size="X-Large" />
</asp:Calendar>
```

And use:

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
  cld_birth.SelectedDate = new DateTime(2003, 1, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do as @Martin-Brennan suggests, but the code may need to be placed in the Page_PreRender event handler.

```
  protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
      cld_birth.SelectedDate = new DateTime(2003, 1, 1);
      cld_birth.VisibleDate = new DateTime(2003, 1, 1);
    }
  }
```